# Share Bluetooth connection between device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

With WiFi you can control which device can connect to your WiFi device by managing which devices know the SSID+wpa2 couple. Is it possible to do the same thing in bluetooth?

In other words, I want to be able to do with Bluetooth what I do in WiFi by connecting two devices with a default SSID+wpa2, once the connection is established, automatically generate new SSID+wpa2 and share this couple to control which others devices can connect.